# Preloading image sequence on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, image, canvas, preload, smoothing

I have this animation where I show 143 images in 5880ms. The problem is that the animation is not running smoothly and I think it must have to be that I need to preload these images on the canvas.

Here is the code:

```
//Request animation standarization for all browsers
var getRequestAnimationFrame = function () {
   return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
       window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
       window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
       function ( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(enroute, 1000/41);
            //41 fps
       };
};


setTimeout(function(){

    var imgNumber = 1;
var lastImgNumber = 143;

var canvas = document.getElementById('utn');    
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
       ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height );
   ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
 };

var fpAnimationFrame = getRequestAnimationFrame();
var timer = function(){
    if (imgNumber>lastImgNumber){
        clearInterval( timer );
    }else{
            img.src = "img/utn_"+( imgNumber++ )+".png";
        fpAnimationFrame(timer);
      }
    };
fpAnimationFrame(timer); //Call animation the first time    
}, 6180); //the animation starts at 6.18s
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, preloading would be advisable. See also [YAIL](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/YAIL-imageLoader-for-JavaScript) preloader :)

Answer (score 0):

yes maybe you need to preload all the images and then, show the sequence. You nee to use an image preloader, you can find multiple preloaders on this website. http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-preloader-image/page/2/